# How to hide bottom info of DataGrid MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I' using DataGrid from MUI and i really want to hide this, how can i do this, thanks
[image]

Answer (score 5):

For removing all the footer you can use

> hideFooter: If true, the footer component is hidden.

You can check that here on the documentacion for the DataGrid https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#footer

As well this prevent the problem you mention previously in comment above

> Thank for your answers, it definetely did the job, but one problem is,
> it still leave blank line at bottom, how can i get rid of that, here
> is image of that ibb.co/25mZJ1X

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

you can use `hideFooterPagination` and `hideFooterSelectedRowCount` in props dataGrid

```
 <DataGrid
    rows={rows}
    columns={columns}
    hideFooterPagination
    hideFooterSelectedRowCount
  />
```

Comment: Thank for your answers, it definetely did the job, but one problem is, it still leave blank line at bottom, how can i get rid of that, here is image of that https://ibb.co/25mZJ1X

Comment: <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} 
      hideFooterPagination
      hideFooterSelectedRowCount
      hideFooter
 />